# Language switcher doesn't appear

Tags: theming, i18n-l10n

I have enabled the "locale" and "content translation" modules. Also I have two languages in my Drupal, Spanish and English, after that I have configured the detention method by URL.

I have finished my English page and I just need to translate the website to Spanish. When I set the language switcher to the website (the header or a columns) of my Structure I don't see anything. I can click on "translate" button of the blocks of my web, I see the "spanish" option, I click in "translate", but I get this message:

> This string uses the Full HTML text format. Strings with this format
>   are not allowed for translation.

Ok, I change the format to Plain Text but I lost my HTML format, styles... I can't translate and I can't see the switcher to change to Spanish or English.

Drupal version 7.4.

Comment: FYI: 7.4 is not the last ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To translate custom block text you need to do the following:

1. Download the [Internationalisation module (i18n)](https://www.drupal.org/project/i18n)
2. Enable String translation module (i18n_string)
3. Go to Configuration > Regional & Language > Multilingual Settings >
   Strings (admin/config/regional/i18n/strings)
4. Enable Full HTML in Translatable text formats
5. Save

Comment: oh, this is great !, but I need to set the switcher to my website to allow the user choose the language... also, when I traslate a text, how I get the url to my new languages? 

I pulse "traslate" I change the text but I don´t see the new page.

Comment: I think you have a few different issues here. To make it easier for people to help you try to break down your question into a clear step-by-step description of what you are doing.

Comment: There is a good tutorial [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/275705)  for setting up a multilingual site with Content Translation (as opposed to Entity Translation, which is an alternative way to translate nodes)